# Gradle: How do I override a variable in a subproject?

Tags: gradle

I define use a string that contains a variable in the root project's `build.gradle`, and I'd like to define the value of that variable differently in the `build.gradle`s of different subprojects.

Root `build.gradle`:

```
ext {
    diet4jActivationClass = 'xxx'
}
subprojects {
    ...
    publishing {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                from(components.java)

                pom {
                    properties = [
                        'diet4j.activationclass': "${diet4jActivationClass}"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Subproject's `build.gradle`:

```
ext {
    diet4jActivationClass = 'yyy'
}
```

The POM property always gets generated with value `xxx` and never with `yyy`. How do I do this?

Comment: are you using `subprojects { ... }` in the first file?

Comment: Yes. Edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the root project will evaluate before it's children. So the `subprojects {...}` block in the root project will evaluate before the child `build.gradle` files evaluate. So, at the time when `subprojects {...}` block is evaluated there's no override for the property.

You can call `evaluationDependsOnChildren()` in the root project to flip the ordering but I don't recommend that as it can cause other issues.

Perhaps you could use a closure to delay the evaluation of the property?

Another option is to declare the properties in the root build.gradle rather than the sub project build.gradle.

Eg:

```
project(':xxx') {
   ext {
       diet4jActivationClass = 'xxx'
   }
}
project(':yyy') {
   ext {
       diet4jActivationClass = 'yyy'
   }
} 
subprojects {...}
```

Or yet another option is to use an `afterEvaluate {...}` closure (I really hate this approach but sometimes it's the only way)

```
subprojects {
   afterEvaluate {...} 
}
```

Comment: I tried with closures, but failed: same result. (That's very possibly because I did them wrong.) But defining them in the root project works! I'm not a great fan of that structure, but better something that works than nothing!

Comment: As I said, there's always `afterEvaluate {...} `. This would allow you to keep the config in the child build.gradle